# Mysql Query Insert querk

Tags: mysql

**Im having a little trouble understanding the reasoning behind an error i was getting and it's solution.**

```
mysql> explain times;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| person_id  | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| desc       | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| in         | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| out        | timestamp   | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| clocked_in | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 1                   |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**When i tried to insert values into the times table i was getting this error with this command**

```
mysql> insert into times(person_id, desc) values(1,'stuff');

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'desc) values(1,'stuff')' at line 1
```

**but then for whatever reason, mostly because i have had to use thing to escpape stings i used**

```
insert into times(person_id, `desc`) values(1, 'stuff')
```

**and then**

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
```

**why did this work??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`desc` is a reserved word in MySQL and must be surrounded with the ` character when being referenced as a column.

`desc` is a sort order instructing MySQL to sort the returned results in descending order.

Please see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: ohh...well..guess i should be more careful with my names.

Comment: Naming a column `desc` certainly does make examining sql queries and table structures a bit more complex. `description` may be a better choice.

Comment: it's kind of funny now because desc is highlighted blue in the post(indicating a code keyword).

Answer (score 1):

`desc` is a keyword in mysql or sql or any other database which describe descending but when you use `'desc'` it will take that as a column name

Answer (score 1):

`DESC` and `IN` are two KEYWORDS in mysql